# Search only last n lines of a file for matching text pattern and print filenames that do not have this pattern

Tags: bash, grep, tail

I would like to search the last 2 lines of a bunch of similarly named files for a given text pattern and write out the filenames where matches are **NOT** found.

I tried this:

```
tail -n 2 slurm-* | grep -L "run complete"
```

As you can see "slurm" is the file base, and I want to find files where "run complete" is absent.  However, this command does not give me any output.  I tried the regular (non-inverse) problem:

```
tail -n 2 slurm-* | grep -H "run complete"
```

and I get a bunch of output (all the matches that are found but not the filenames):

```
(standard input):run complete
```

I figure that I have misunderstood how piping tail output to grep works, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The piping sends the result of the tail to the grep.  That means only the last to lines are sent, not the filenames.

Comment: If a file doesn't have the string "run complete" then print the last two lines of the file + the filename?

Comment: @Nic3500 my confusion here is that when I run just the tail command from my question it gives the filename and last two lines in the output... so, isn't the filename part of the tail output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
for file in `ls slurm-*`;
do
res=`tail -n2 $file | grep "run complete" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?`;
  if [ $res -ne 0 ];
  then
    echo $file ;
  fi ;
done ;
```

Explanation -

"echo $?" gives us the return code of the grep command. If grep finds the pattern in the file, it returns 0. Otherwise the return code is non-zero.

We check for this non-zero return code, and only then, "echo" the file name. Since you have not mentioned whether the output of grep is necessary, I have discarded the STD_OUT and STD_ERR by sending it to /dev/null.